# SharedPreferences to get last saved number image issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app InfiniteGallery class , by press button you can save any image to SD card , to  Get Last Saved Number and Store the last Number of saved image so you can Store **All Images in Sequential Order**  , but when add SharedPreferences , i have red line error under :

1- `SharedPreferences savedNumber = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);`
(under :getSharedPreferences).

**error is : create method 'getSharedPreferences'(string,int)'**

2- `SharedPreferences saveNumber = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);`
(under :getApplicationContext).

**error is :create method 'getApplicationContext()'**

i tried to fix it but icant , any advice or help will be appreciated , thanks

my code:

```
   View vi=convertView; 
    final ViewHolder holder; 
    if(convertView==null){ 
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_items, null); 
        holder=new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 
        holder.button=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_save);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mContext.getResources(), images[itemPos]);
         holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);           
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  private Bitmap bm;
  private String PREFS_NAME;
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
       if(!myDir.exists()){
           myDir.mkdirs();}

        SharedPreferences savedNumber = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
        int lastSavedNumber = savedNumber.getInt("lastsavednumber",0); 
        lastSavedNumber++; 
        String fname = "Image-"+lastSavedNumber+".png"; 

        File file = new File (myDir, fname); 
        if (file.exists ()) {file.delete (); } 
        try { 
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                 //Your Bitmap from the resouce 
        out.flush(); 
        out.close(); 
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
         catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); }

       SharedPreferences saveNumber = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
               (PREFS_NAME, 0); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorset = saveNumber.edit(); 
        editorset.putInt("lastsavednumber",lastSavedNumber); 
        editorset.commit();
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG). 
                 show();}});

      vi.setTag(holder);}

    else holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag(); 
    holder.text.setText(name[itemPos]); 

    final int stub_id=images[itemPos]; 
    holder.image.setImageResource(stub_id); 

    return vi; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what that red line says but here I believe it is because you are missing `Context`. Change it to

```
SharedPreferences savedNumber = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

and

```
SharedPreferences saveNumber = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

Depending on where you are in the app you may need `ActivityName.this` where `ActivityName` is the name of the `Activity` you are in

Comment: thanks for answering ,im out now once reach home i will check it and post the error detail

Comment: Ok, this should solve the problem because you definitely need a `Context` to access them

Comment: i apply it but still red line error , check updated post for declairing the error , please thanks

Comment: And you changed both to `ActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences()`?

Comment: i did that : ActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences() , the same still error

Comment: Is this code inside of an `Activity`? And, silly question, but you are using the actual `Activity` name in place of `ActivityName`, correct?

Comment: yes inside activity , yes also Activity name in place of ActivityName

Comment: Try cleaning your project and make sure you don't have any other errors. That should work

Answer (score 0):

This is all because you are in a scope of a class that doesn't have this method.

What you can do is one of the next things:

1. have a parameter of type Context in the function and use it for using the method "getSharedPreferences".
2. have a field of type Context , and set it in the CTOR of your class.
3. if your class is inside a class that extends Context, instead of this.getSharedPreferences, write the name of the class and then ".this.getSharedPreferences" .
4. create a global static variable that will hold the application instance. you can instatiate it in the onCreate() of the application class. whenever you need a context, you can use it instead of passing an instance between classes and methods.